# Runtime-Error 1004 Program crashes when creating chart

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I've been out of learning programming for a month. When I last left off the code ran perfectly with no issues, now the program crashes when trying to create a chart ( I am importing data from an access database through recordset and then manipulating it in a hidden sheet and finally exporting and importing it to an imagebox in my userform.

Error message: Run time error "1004": Application-defined or object defined error

The code, it crashes in the createchart procedure.

```
Public Sub Create(TickerID As String, StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date)

    Call ImportData(TickerID, StartDate, EndDate)
    Call CreateHeadings(TickerID)
    Call CreateChart
    Call DisplayChart

End Sub
Private Sub ImportData(TickerID As String, StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date)

    Const ConnectionPath As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\name\Desktop\DataBase.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

    Dim DataConnection As ADODB.Connection: Set DataConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim RecordSet As ADODB.RecordSet: Set RecordSet = New ADODB.RecordSet

    DataConnection.ConnectionString = ConnectionPath
    DataConnection.Open

    Dim SQLString As String: SQLString = "SELECT * FROM " _
    & TickerID _
    & " WHERE [Date] BETWEEN #" & StartDate & "# AND #" & EndDate & "#"

    With RecordSet
        .ActiveConnection = DataConnection
        .Source = SQLString
        .LockType = adLockReadOnly
        .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
        .Open
    End With

    ' Copies Data from RecordSet to Hidden Sheet "Chart", good for further investigating the data if necessary too
    Worksheets("Chart").Cells.ClearContents
    Worksheets("Chart").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset RecordSet

    Set RecordSet = Nothing
    Set DataConnection = Nothing
End Sub
Private Sub CreateHeadings(TickerID As String)

    Const ConnectionPath As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\name\Desktop\DataBase.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

    Dim DataConnection As ADODB.Connection: Set DataConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim RecordSet As ADODB.RecordSet: Set RecordSet = New ADODB.RecordSet

    DataConnection.ConnectionString = ConnectionPath
    DataConnection.Open

    Dim SQLString As String: SQLString = "SELECT * FROM " _
    & TickerID & " where 1 = 2"

    With RecordSet
        .ActiveConnection = DataConnection
        .Source = SQLString
        .LockType = adLockReadOnly
        .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
        .Open
    End With

    For i = 0 To RecordSet.Fields.Count - 1
        Dim x As String
        Worksheets("chart").Cells(1, 1 + i).Value = RecordSet.Fields(i).Name
        Next i
End Sub
Private Sub CreateChart()
    ' Create new graph and export to be imported in userform image control

    Dim OHLCChart As ChartObject
    Set OHLCChart = Sheets("Chart").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Range("A10") _
    .Left, Width:=500, Top:=Range("a10").Top, Height:=300)

    With OHLCChart.Chart ****<- CRASHES HERE!****
        .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Chart").Range("A2:E2", Range("E2").End(xlDown)) 
        .ChartType = xlStockOHLC
        .ChartArea.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("C")) + 5
        .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Columns("D")) - 5
        .Export ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp.bmp" ' Export as Gif
    End With

'        OHLCChart.Delete
End Sub
Private Sub DisplayChart()

    ' Loads the graph image Path: temp.gif on desktop - should be changed to combobox - change procedure
    If MainWindow.Img_Chart_Picture.Picture = Enabled Then
        MainWindow.Img_Chart_Picture.Default
    Else
        MainWindow.Img_Chart_Picture.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp.bmp")
    End If
End Sub
```

What could be wrong? Again, last time for about a month ago everything worked flawlessly.

Comment: How does it crash?  Any error message?

Comment: I've not my laptop here, but if my memory works well the `ChartObject` has a property which is `Charts` and it's a collection. So it probably crashes because you say `With obj.Chart`, while it should be something like `With obj.Charts(1)` (if the object contains a single chart, as it should be by default since you don't specify any number in the previous statement)

Comment: P.s. anyway post the error message, that will probably be something about the property has not been found (`With block not set`, I think)

Comment: This `.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Chart").Range("A2:E2", Range("E2").End(xlDown))` may fail if the sheet "chart" is not active.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ - a `ChartObject` only has one `Chart`

Comment: @TimWilliams correct, I think I made confusion with the Charts method (returning indeed a Chart object). Sorry, didn't have way to test so I've just expressed a (wrong) feeling. Still would be nice to know the error message.

Comment: The error message is: Run time error "1004": Application-defined or object defined error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - note you should always qualify every use of `Range()` with a worksheet object

```
Private Sub CreateChart()
    ' Create new graph and export to be imported in userform image control

    Dim OHLCChart As ChartObject
    Dim rng As Range, sht as WorkSheet

    Set sht = Sheets("Chart")
    Set OHLCChart = sht.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=sht.Range("A10").Left, _
                      Width:=500, Top:=sht.Range("a10").Top, Height:=300)

    Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Range("A2:E2"), sht.Range("E2").End(xlDown))

    With OHLCChart.Chart 
        .SetSourceData Source:=rng
        .ChartType = xlStockOHLC
        .ChartArea.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(sht.Columns("C")) + 5
        .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(sht.Columns("D")) - 5
        .Export ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp.bmp" ' Export as Gif
    End With

'        OHLCChart.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: May i ask, why do i need to qualify Range() with a worksheet object? Doesn't VBA handle it automatically?

Comment: Something very strange is going on, when I first start my program it runs it creates the chart and all data is correctly linked in the chart but there are anyway no lines! When one changes the date ( reruns it after first attempt it SOMETIMES makes it correct and everything is shown as should be. What could be the issue?

Comment: I don't have access to a PC for the next week or so, so I can't answer your second question.  For your first one- yes VBA will attempt to assign a worksheet if you don't specify one, but it always uses the active sheet (for code in a regular module) or the associated worksheet (if your code is in a sheet module).  These may not be the sheet you wanted.  As you develop code you can add new code which ends up changing the ActiveSheet, which may then break older code.

Comment: @TimWilliams, would you expect this to cause similar problems when doing something like `Range(sht.Range(), sht.Range())`.  That is, where the outer `Range` is unqualified, but its component start and end Ranges are fully qualified?